# Custom WordPress Menu for posts

Tags: php, array, security, iteration, wordpress

I have recently delved into the world of OOP programming with PHP. I wanted to add my own custom menu to the WordPress Admin area, and came across a tutorial, which I have followed, and the code is currently working.

What I would like to know is: whether this is the correct way to go about it, is it secure (since it deals with storing stuff in the Database) and can it be improved upon?

```
class AddMenu extends TheGlobalSettings {

public $default = array(
        'slug'          =>      '',
        'title'         =>      '',
        'page_title'    =>      '',
        'parent'        =>      null,
        'id'            =>      '',
        'capability'    =>      'manage_options',
        'icon'          =>      'dashicons-hammer',
        'position'      =>      null,
        'desc'          =>      '',
        'function'      =>      ''
    );

public $parentID    =   null;

public $menu_options    =   array();

function __construct( $options ) {

    $this->menu_options = array_merge( $this->default, $options );

    if( $this->menu_options['slug'] == '' ) :

        return;

    endif;

    $this->settings_id = $this->menu_options['slug'];

    $this->prepopulate();

    add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_page' ) );

    add_action( 'wordpressmenu_page_save_' . $this->settings_id, array( $this, 'save_settings' ) );
}

public function prepopulate() {

    if( $this->menu_options['title'] == '') :

        $this->menu_options['title'] = ucfirst( $this->menu_options['slug'] );

    endif;

    if( $this->menu_options['page_title'] = '' ) :

        $this->menu_options['page_title'] = $this->menu_options['title'];

    endif;
}

public function add_page() {

    $functionToUse = $this->menu_options['function'];

    if( $functionToUse == '' ) :

        $functionToUse = array( $this, 'create_menu_page' );

    endif;

    if( $this->parent_id != null ) :

        add_submenu_page(
                $this->parent_id,
                $this->menu_options['page_title'],
                $this->menu_options['title'],
                $this->menu_options['capability'],
                $this->menu_options['slug'],
                $functionToUse
            );

    else :

        add_menu_page( 
                $this->menu_options['page_title'],
                $this->menu_options['title'],
                $this->menu_options['capability'],
                $this->menu_options['slug'],
                $functionToUse,
                $this->menu_options['icon'],
                $this->menu_options['position']
            );

    endif;
}

public function create_menu_page() {

    $this->save_if_submit();

    $tab = 'general';

    if( isset( $_GET['tab'] ) ) :

        $tab = $_GET['tab'];

    endif;

    $this->init_settings(); ?>

    <div class="wrap">
        <h2><?php echo $this->menu_options['page_title']; ?></h2>

        <?php if( !empty( $this->menu_options['desc'] ) ) : ?>
        <p class="description"><?php echo $this->menu_options['desc']; ?></p>
        <?php endif;?>

        <?php $this->render_tabs(); ?>

        <form method="POST" action="">
            <div class="postbox">
                <div class="inside">
                    <table class="form-table">
                        <?php $this->render_fields( $tab ); ?>
                    </table>
                    <?php $this->save_button(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>

<?php
}

public function render_tabs( $active_tab = 'general' ) {

    if( count( $this->tabs ) > 1 ) {

        echo '<h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper woo-nav-tab-wrapper">';

            foreach ($this->tabs as $key => $value) :

                echo '<a href="' . admin_url('admin.php?page=' . $this->menu_options['slug'] . '&tab=' . $key ) . '" class="nav-tab ' .  ( ( $key == $active_tab ) ? 'nav-tab-active' : '' ) . ' ">' . $value . '</a>';

            endforeach;

        echo '</h2>';
        echo '<br/>';
    }
}
/**
 * Render the save button
 * @return void 
 */
protected function save_button() { 
    ?>
    <button type="submit" name="<?php echo $this->settings_id; ?>_save" class="button button-primary">
        <?php _e( 'Save', 'textdomain' ); ?>
    </button>
    <?php
}
/**
 * Save if the button for this menu is submitted
 * @return void 
 */
protected function save_if_submit() {
    if( isset( $_POST[ $this->settings_id . '_save' ] ) ) {
        do_action( 'wordpressmenu_page_save_' . $this->settings_id );
    }
}
}

class AddSubPage extends AddMenu {

function __construct( $options, AddMenu $parent ) {

    parent::__construct( $options );

    $this->parent_id = $parent->settings_id;
}

}

class WordPressMenuTab {

public $slug;
public $title;
public $menu;

function __construct( $options, AddMenu $menu ) {

    $this->slug = $options['slug'];
    $this->title = $options['title'];
    $this->menu = $menu;
    $this->menu->add_tab( $options );
}

/**
 * Add field to this tab
 * @param [type] $array [description]
 */
public function add_field( $array ){
    $this->menu->add_field( $array, $this->slug );
}
}

abstract class TheGlobalSettings {
/**
 * ID of the settings
 * @var string
 */
public $settings_id = '';
/**
 * Tabs for the settings page
 * @var array
 */
public $tabs = array( 
    'general' => 'General' );
/**
 * Settings from database
 * @var array
 */
protected $settings = array();
/**
 * Array of fields for the general tab
 * array(
 *  'tab_slug' => array(
 *      'field_name' => array(),
 *      ),
 *  )
 * @var array
 */
protected $fields = array();
/** 
 * Data gotten from POST
 * @var array
 */
protected $posted_data = array();

public function init_settings() {
    $this->settings = (array) get_option( $this->settings_id );
    foreach ( $this->fields as $tab_key => $tab ) {
        
        foreach ( $tab as $name => $field ) {
            
            if( isset( $this->settings[ $name ] ) ) {
                $this->fields[ $tab_key ][ $name ]['default'] = $this->settings[ $name ];
            }   
        
        }
    }
}
/**
 * Save settings from POST
 * @return [type] [description]
 */
public function save_settings(){
    
    $this->posted_data = $_POST;
    if( empty( $this->settings ) ) {
        $this->init_settings();
    }
    foreach ($this->fields as $tab => $tab_data ) {
        foreach ($tab_data as $name => $field) {
            
            $this->settings[ $name ] = $this->{ 'validate_' . $field['type'] }( $name );
    
        }
    }
    update_option( $this->settings_id, $this->settings );   
}
/**
 * Gets and option from the settings API, using defaults if necessary to prevent undefined notices.
 *
 * @param  string $key
 * @param  mixed  $empty_value
 * @return mixed  The value specified for the option or a default value for the option.
 */
public function get_option( $key, $empty_value = null ) {
    if ( empty( $this->settings ) ) {
        $this->init_settings();
    }
    // Get option default if unset.
    if ( ! isset( $this->settings[ $key ] ) ) {
        $form_fields = $this->fields;
        foreach ( $this->tabs as $tab_key => $tab_title ) {
            if( isset( $form_fields[ $tab_key ][ $key ] ) ) {
                $this->settings[ $key ] = isset( $form_fields[ $tab_key ][ $key ]['default'] ) ? $form_fields[ $tab_key ][ $key ]['default'] : '';
            
            }
        }
        
    }
    if ( ! is_null( $empty_value ) && empty( $this->settings[ $key ] ) && '' === $this->settings[ $key ] ) {
        $this->settings[ $key ] = $empty_value;
    }
    return $this->settings[ $key ];
}




public function validate_text( $key ){
        $text  = $this->get_option( $key );
        if ( isset( $this->posted_data[ $key ] ) ) {
            $text = wp_kses_post( trim( stripslashes( $this->posted_data[ $key ] ) ) );
        }
        return $text;
    }
    /**
     * Validate textarea field
     * @param  string $key name of the field
     * @return string      
     */
    public function validate_textarea( $key ){
        $text  = $this->get_option( $key );
         
        if ( isset( $this->posted_data[ $key ] ) ) {
            $text = wp_kses( trim( stripslashes( $this->posted_data[ $key ] ) ),
                array_merge(
                    array(
                        'iframe' => array( 'src' => true, 'style' => true, 'id' => true, 'class' => true )
                    ),
                    wp_kses_allowed_html( 'post' )
                )
            );
        }
        return $text;
    }
    /**
     * Validate WPEditor field
     * @param  string $key name of the field
     * @return string      
     */
    public function validate_wpeditor( $key ){
        $text  = $this->get_option( $key );
         
        if ( isset( $this->posted_data[ $key ] ) ) {
            $text = wp_kses( trim( stripslashes( $this->posted_data[ $key ] ) ),
                array_merge(
                    array(
                        'iframe' => array( 'src' => true, 'style' => true, 'id' => true, 'class' => true )
                    ),
                    wp_kses_allowed_html( 'post' )
                )
            );
        }
        return $text;
    }
    /**
     * Validate select field
     * @param  string $key name of the field
     * @return string      
     */
    public function validate_select( $key ) {
        $value = $this->get_option( $key );
        if ( isset( $this->posted_data[ $key ] ) ) {
            $value = stripslashes( $this->posted_data[ $key ] );
        }
        return $value;
    }
    /**
     * Validate radio
     * @param  string $key name of the field
     * @return string      
     */
    public function validate_radio( $key ) {
        $value = $this->get_option( $key );
        if ( isset( $this->posted_data[ $key ] ) ) {
            $value = stripslashes( $this->posted_data[ $key ] );
        }
        return $value;
    }
    /**
     * Validate checkbox field
     * @param  string $key name of the field
     * @return string      
     */
    public function validate_checkbox( $key ) {
        $status = '';
        if ( isset( $this->posted_data[ $key ] ) && ( 1 == $this->posted_data[ $key ] ) ) {
            $status = '1';
        }
        return $status;
    }

    public function add_field( $array, $tab = 'general' ) {
            $allowed_field_types = array(
                'text',
                'textarea',
                'wpeditor',
                'select',
                'radio',
                'checkbox' );
            // If a type is set that is now allowed, don't add the field
            if( isset( $array['type'] ) &&$array['type'] != '' && ! in_array( $array['type'], $allowed_field_types ) ){
                return;
            }
            $defaults = array(
                'name' => '',
                'title' => '',
                'default' => '',
                'placeholder' => '',
                'type' => 'text',
                'options' => array(),
                'default' => '',
                'desc' => '',
                );
            $array = array_merge( $defaults, $array );
            if( $array['name'] == '' ) {
                return;
            }
            foreach ( $this->fields as $tabs ) {
                if( isset( $tabs[ $array['name'] ] ) ) {
                    trigger_error( 'There is alreay a field with name ' . $array['name'] );
                    return;
                }
            }
            // If there are options set, then use the first option as a default value
            if( ! empty( $array['options'] ) && $array['default'] == '' ) {
                $array_keys = array_keys( $array['options'] );
                $array['default'] = $array_keys[0];
            }
            if( ! isset( $this->fields[ $tab ] ) ) {
                $this->fields[ $tab ] = array();
            }
            $this->fields[ $tab ][ $array['name'] ] = $array;
        }
        
        /**
         * Adding tab
         * @param array $array options
         */
        public function add_tab( $array ) {
            $defaults = array(
                'slug' => '',
                'title' => '' );
            $array = array_merge( $defaults, $array );
            if( $array['slug'] == '' || $array['title'] == '' ){
                return;
            }
            $this->tabs[ $array['slug'] ] = $array['title'];
        }

        public function render_fields( $tab ) {

            if( ! isset( $this->fields[ $tab ] ) ) :

                echo '<p>' . __( 'There are no settings on these page.', 'textdomain' ) . '</p>';
                return;

            endif;

            foreach ( $this->fields[ $tab ] as $name => $field ) :
                
                $this->{ 'render_' . $field['type'] }( $field );

            endforeach;

        }

        public function render_text( $field ){
                extract( $field );
                ?>

                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <label for="<?php echo $name; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></label>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="<?php echo $type; ?>" name="<?php echo $name; ?>" id="<?php echo $name; ?>" value="<?php echo $default; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $placeholder; ?>" />   
                        <?php if( $desc != '' ) {
                            echo '<p class="description">' . $desc . '</p>';
                        }?>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <?php
            }
            /**
             * Render textarea field
             * @param  string $field options
             * @return void      
             */
            public function render_textarea( $field ){
                extract( $field );
                ?>

                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <label for="<?php echo $name; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></label>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <textarea name="<?php echo $name; ?>" id="<?php echo $name; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $placeholder; ?>" ><?php echo $default; ?></textarea>   
                        <?php if( $desc != '' ) {
                            echo '<p class="description">' . $desc . '</p>';
                        }?>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <?php
            }
            /**
             * Render WPEditor field
             * @param  string $field  options
             * @return void      
             */
            public function render_wpeditor( $field ){
                
                extract( $field );
                ?>

                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <label for="<?php echo $name; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></label>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <?php wp_editor( $default, $name, array('wpautop' => false) ); ?>
                        <?php if( $desc != '' ) {
                            echo '<p class="description">' . $desc . '</p>';
                        }?>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <?php
            }
            /**
             * Render select field
             * @param  string $field options
             * @return void      
             */
            public function render_select( $field ) {
                extract( $field );
                ?>

                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <label for="<?php echo $name; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></label>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <select name="<?php echo $name; ?>" id="<?php echo $name; ?>" >
                            <?php 
                                foreach ($options as $value => $text) {
                                    echo '<option ' . selected( $default, $value, false ) . ' value="' . $value . '">' . $text . '</option>';
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                        <?php if( $desc != '' ) {
                            echo '<p class="description">' . $desc . '</p>';
                        }?>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <?php
            }
            /**
             * Render radio
             * @param  string $field options
             * @return void      
             */
            public function render_radio( $field ) {
                extract( $field );
                ?>

                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <label for="<?php echo $name; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></label>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <?php 
                            foreach ($options as $value => $text) {
                                echo '<input name="' . $name . '" id="' . $name . '" type="'.  $type . '" ' . checked( $default, $value, false ) . ' value="' . $value . '">' . $text . '</option><br/>';
                            }
                        ?>
                        <?php if( $desc != '' ) {
                            echo '<p class="description">' . $desc . '</p>';
                        }?>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <?php
            }
            /**
             * Render checkbox field
             * @param  string $field options
             * @return void      
             */
            public function render_checkbox( $field ) {
                extract( $field );
                ?>

                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <label for="<?php echo $name; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></label>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <input <?php checked( $default, '1', true ); ?> type="<?php echo $type; ?>" name="<?php echo $name; ?>" id="<?php echo $name; ?>" value="1" placeholder="<?php echo $placeholder; ?>" />
                        <?php echo $desc; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <?php
            }
}

$newMenu = new AddMenu( array( 
'slug'      =>      'sitesettings',
'title'     =>      'Site Settings',
'desc'      =>      '',
'icon'      =>      '',
'position'  =>      5
)
);

$newMenu->add_field(array(
'name' => 'text',
'title' => 'Text Input',
'desc' => '' ));

$customTab = new WordPressMenuTab( 
array(
    'slug' => 'example_tab', 
    'title' => 'Example Tab' ), 
$newMenu );
```

Answer (score 1):

## Is it secure?

I don't spot any obvious security holes. It appears that code depends on Wordpress functions for storing data in the database so it would be as secure as the Wordpress core code.

## Can it be improved upon?

#### Yes

- Use [docblocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docblock) to document the code

  - above methods to describe the outcome, any parameters, return type, etc.
  - above property/instance variable declarations to note type- this can be useful if the IDE supports it for suggestions
- use [short echo tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) - e.g. instead of

  ```
  <h2><?php echo $this->menu_options['page_title']; ?></h2>
  ```

  It can be simpler:

  ```
  <h2><?= $this->menu_options['page_title']; ?></h2>
  ```
- presuming the PHP engine version used is 5.4 or above the arrays can be expressed using a shorter syntax  - so instead of:

  ```
  array( $this, 'save_settings' )
  ```

  It can be simplified to just:

  ```
  [ $this, 'save_settings' ]
  ```
- eliminate duplicate code - e.g. the implementations for `validate_textarea` and `validate_wpeditor` appear to be identical, and the same is true for `validate_select` and `validate_radio`. A single function in each case could be used and called by the two functions, or the code could be altered to call one of those functions (perhaps renamed) instead of having two separate functions. I see those functions are called dynamically by the `save_settings()` method but perhaps a mapping of types to function names could be used instead of having duplicate functions.